# disapearing part of json file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

```
import codecs, json

line, aktualny_workout, workout_data = None

def czytaj_workout(_line):
    aktualny_workout = codecs.open(_line.strip(), 'r', 'utf-8', 'ignore')
    workout_data = json.load(aktualny_workout)
    return

with codecs.open('./output.txt', 'r', 'utf-8', 'ignore') as f:
    line = f.readline()
    while line:
        czytaj_workout(line)
        line = f.readline()


location_dic = workout_data[0]['points']
print("latitude: ", latitude_dic['latitude'])
print("longitude: ", longitude_dic['longitude'])
print(workout_data[0]['comments']) # >>> KeyError: 'comments'
print([*workout_data]) # rzeczywiście, brakuje sekcji comments
                       # indeed, there is no 'comments' key in workout_data
                       #it's stunnin'
```

Because Endomondo Sport Tracker quits, they sends to users an archive with all stored data (on request).
I want to build from it a pretty pdf file.
Snipplet above reads filenames from list of Endomondo workouts
and prints out some data.
The problem is, it doesn't see any data after the 'points' tag/key. And there is tag/key 'comments' located. Could anyone explain me what happens?

Here is a part of data I work on:

```
[
    {"name": "z Marianowa"},
    {"sport": "CYCLING_TRANSPORTATION"},
    {"source": "TRACK_MOBILE"},
    {"created_date": "2012-07-12 15:16:18.0"},
        .
        .
        .
    {"descend_m": 180},
    {"points": [
        [
            {"location": [[
                {"latitude": 53.3775774},
                {"longitude": 15.2635784}
            ]]},
            {"altitude": 81.5},
            {"timestamp": "Thu Jul 12 12:07:41 UTC 2012"}
        ],
        [
            {"location": [[
                {"latitude": 53.377387},
                {"longitude": 15.2634523}
            ]]},
            {"altitude": 81.5},
            {"distance_km": 0.022},
            {"speed_kmh": 15.52},
            {"timestamp": "Thu Jul 12 12:07:46 UTC 2012"}
        ],

    ]},
    {"comments": [[
        {"author": "Andrzej Kryński"},
        {"created_date": "2012-07-12 15:41:54.0"},
        {"text": "Lepiej jechać przez Pęzino i Ulikowo: mały ruch, prawie żaden więc bezpiecznie, dobra nawierzchnia i najlepsze osiągi na tym odcinku."}
    ]]}
]
```

Comment: Mind showing a sample of that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recommendations:

- I would suggest using pathlib for file handling in Python 3.
- You need to stop treating workout_data like a global var from inside a function,
  if you are going to use a function return the variable you changed (there are exceptions but for now just accept this as a general rule).
- Watch this ["loop like a native video"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EnSu9hHGq5o&t=1s) so you understand why I restructured your while loop like something below.
- when you are working with dictionary data you aren't sure is going to be there, use .get() syntax instead of d["variable"].  the .get() tries it but hands back None if it's not found.  The other hands back an error.
- Next time you pose a question on SO please include a bit of the data so we know what we are working with.

EDIT: After the json file was posted I found that the format was bad but it was completely json files not a file with json records.  So the first thing to do was fix the format.

```
import json
from pathlib import Path

my_file = Path('./output.txt')

bad_data_format = json.loads(my_file.read_text())
workout_data = dict()
for x in bad_data_format:
    workout_data.update(x)
bad_points_format = data.get('points')

# the same technique need to be used on bad_points_format as bad_data_format.  I leave this to homework

print(f"comments: {workout_data.get('comments')}")
```

Comment: The snippet is only a snippet, I didn't want to copy my code exactly, but really I forget the get method exists. 
Unfortunately 'get('comments')' returns 'None' so it fails too.
It means,  your answer helps nothing. But thanks.

Comment: workout_data[-1] points to 'location', not to 'comments' so comments are not read in from file...
This is the question. Why?

Comment: And what about 'output.txt':
os.chdir("C:\\Users\\Andrzej\\Downloads\\endomondo-2021-01-27\\Workouts\\")
os.system("dir /B /A:-D > .\\output.txt")
The very last line of 'output.txt' is 'output.txt' itself, as a string ;)

Comment: get('comments') doesn't fail, it returns 'None' which is not an error condition. It means that comments isn't in the dictionary. I can take guesses but without the data I won't be sure. The file format doesn't sounds like it's lines of json.  You can't create "output.txt" that way and expect a json parser to figure out what you mean by it.  The easiest way to do testing on what you want is to take one line out of output.txt and make another file and do your testing on that.

Comment: do refresh your browser. I edited my post and added those data.
The original file (one of many) one can find at https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vKRRIgjC2uXQes3v2mZMJMg0V9dpJaqo/view?usp=sharing
I solved my problem, not using the get method what is not so elegant, but still I am interested if someone, perhaps you, can do it better.
 In your example get doesn't find 'comments' because this is one of 'workout_data' tags, not the 'points'. 'points' themselfs are dictionary , nested in 'workout_data'.